# What syntax changes need to be made when running a Python program in Codecademy Labs (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7

My school had a math problem of the week question that said:
"Between 1 and 100, there are exactly 5 numbers with exactly 12 factors. What are they?"
So I wrote this quick code for it:

```
# Between 1 and 100, there are exactly 5 numbers with exactly 12 factors. What are they?
x = 1
list_of_five = []
list_of_factors = []
while x < 101:
    y = 1
    list_of_factors = []
    while y < (x+1):
        if (x/y) == int(x/y) and not((x/y) in list_of_factors):
            list_of_factors.append((x/y))
            if len(list_of_factors) == 12:
                list_of_five.append(x)
                print(str(x) + ":")
                print(list_of_factors)
        y+=1
    x+=1
print("The list of numbers is:" + str(list_of_five)) #This should be the solution to the problem.
```

It works just fine in PyCharm, running Python 3.4 (I believe) and it returns 60, 72, 84, 90, and 96 as the five numbers.  So that's all fine and dandy.  But when I wanted to share it with my math teacher (because I don't think he has Python installed on his computer) I copied it to Codecademy Labs (which runs Python 2.7):
http://labs.codecademy.com/DECR#:workspace

When it is run there, it thinks all the numbers from 42 - 100 have 12 factors but they don't.

What needs to change from the code that runs on my computer to the code on Codecademy Labs?  Thanks.

Comment: You're running afoul of [PEP-238](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/). In Python 2, the `/` operator does classic division (flooring for int/long operands). In Python 3, it does true division. If you add `from __future__ import division` to change to the Python 3 division behavior, your script will work fine in Python 2.7.

Comment: Sweet! It worked.  Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CHANGING YOUR CODE**

You would have to add `from __future__ import division` to the beginning of your code. Python 2.7 will do an 'int division' (like // does in Python 3) if you use the / operator. The import will change this.

**ANOTHER SERVICE**

I have pasted your code in [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/bGoF9WP6dqPwS6c1), which does essentially the same as CodeAcadamy. It supports many Python versions, as well as other programming languages.